# List from Django to table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a list in Django and I would like to transfer it to JavaScript table

My template print latest_question_list in loop properly:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for row in latest_question_list %}
            <li>{{ row.mounth }}, {{ row.number1 }}, {{ row.number2 }}, {{ row.number3 }}, {{ row.number4 }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>These list is empty.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

But I would see it in JavaScript (in the same file) in this form:

```
<script>
   var data_table = [600, 194, 345, 512, 200, 320, 328, 498, 267, 349, 287, 276];

[...]

</script>
```

Comment: That isn't a table, and the template is not JS.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the list to the template and use `var data_table = {{ the_list }}`? I don't understand the need for the `for` loops in HTML and then a JS function that just defines a name - the two look totally unrelated.

Comment: Can you please explain your question more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Thanx! I understood my mistake after read "roganjosh" post. Now my code work properly: In Django I make context with data_table and in JavaScript I read by var data_table = "{{ data_table }}"